# soql - cross object - workbadge and workbadgedefinition

Tags: soql, work.com

Ok, according to the ERD workbadge has a lookup to workbadgedefinition:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_badge.htm#topic-title

So why can't I get this simple query to work:

```
Select Id, Description, WorkBadgeDefinition.Name from WorkBadge
```

I keep getting a malformed query.

Also, Is there a easy visual way to build these cross object queries, I am using the workbench right now.

Comment: use eclipse with force.com IDE  for building queries .Force.com IDE has a schema integrated to assist you

Comment: have you tried **Definition.Name** instead **WorkBadgeDefinition.Name**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `Select Id, Description, Definition.Name from WorkBadge`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ratan, I just hit on that as well.

The documentation appears to be out of date or mistyped.

Here is the working query:

```
Select ID, Definition.Name from WorkBadge
```

Definition is how you call WorkBadgeDefinition.  The documentation article for workbadge calls this field DefinitionID.

Comment: Yeah. Definition is the relationship name of WorkBadgeDefinition. You can check any of the sobject relationship name. Best way open eclipse and check sobject in project schema.